# Install Custom extention(Vsix) from your pc in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

Hi there i would like to install an extension into visual studio 2015.
the file is a .vsix file and is located on my desktop.

when i go to visual studio--> options--> extensions and updates--> additional extensions galleries --> add, it asks for a name and URL.

when i add a URL path to the file it says it cannot find it. can someone guide me as to how the URL should be structured so visual studio can find it.

thanks

Comment: Just double-click the .vsix and it should install.

Comment: The vsix IS an installer.